# Accessing external database from Android app

Tags: android, database, sqlite, data-transfer

I have a sqlite database with about 15MB of data (too large to store on each device).  I am building an app to interact with this data.  How to go about accessing the database from wherever the app is being stored.  I'm not asking someone to do it for me, but where do I go about researching how to do this.  Is there an android module that does just this after being passed an ip address (or FTP Server IP?).  Where do I start researching the best way to host my database and then link it to my app?  What's the high level brief of how this is accomplished?  Thanks!

Comment: [Web services](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Web_service) have been around for 15+ years and underlie most of the major Web sites and mobile apps in use today.

Answer (score 1):

Two ways

1. You can send a query to the web server and retrieve the result (you need the web server URL that received your query and send the result through HTTP).
2. You can download the database and put it in the app database directory and then you can query this database.